# I want to find an explicit direct sum decomposition of the space into T-cyclic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

I construct a linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L(\mathbf{C}^7)}$ , where the minimal polynomial is $m_T (x) = x^2(x-1)^2$ and the caraterisitic polynomial is  $p_T (x) = x^3(x - 1)^4$.

The linear operator that I construct is
$$T:
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\\x_7\\
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\  
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\\x_7\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
**I want to find an explicit direct sum decomposition of the space into T-cyclic subspaces**